# How to add HyperLink with JsPDF?

Tags: jspdf

Is it possible to add `HyperLink` in `jsPDF`?

Here is my code which I am using for the same.

```
    var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt'); 
    doc.fromHTML(
     '<a href="http://www.google.com">Click Here</a>',
     35,
     25,
     {
         'width': 180, 'elementHandlers': elementHandler
     });
     doc.save("info.pdf");
```

Comment: Hi, you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 31):

I got the solution after sicking from last two hours.
there is also a method in jsPDF which is not so popular i.e.

```
doc.textWithLink('Click here', x, y, { url: 'http://www.google.com' });
```

Hope it will help someone :)